# Lagrange multiplier does not find global minimum

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to minimize the function
$$f(r_1,r_2,r_3)=\frac{1}{6}(r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2)-(\frac{1}{r_1^3}+\frac{1}{r_2^3}+\frac{1}{r_3^3})$$
subject to the conditions:
$$g(r_1,r_2,r_3)=\frac{1}{3}(r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2)-3(\frac{1}{r_1^3}+\frac{1}{r_2^3}+\frac{1}{r_3^3})=0$$
$$r_1,r_2,r_3\geq0$$
The first thing I notice is that the inequality constraints are not active. So I set
$$\nabla f(r_1,r_2,r_3)=\lambda\nabla g(r_1,r_2,r_3)$$
which gives me $$\lambda=\frac{r_i^5+9}{2r_i^5+27}$$ for each $i=1,2,3$. Since $\lambda$ is the same for each equation, I start to inspect the new function $h(r)=\frac{r^5+9}{2r^5+27}$, which is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$. So in order to minimize $f$, $r_i$'s must be the same. Then I plug this into the equality constraint and find $f=(\frac{3}{2})^\frac{2}{5}3^\frac{-3}{5}$
However, this does not give me the global minimum, which is when $r_1+r_2=r_3$ and $r_1=r_2$. But in that case, $\lambda$ is not a constant for each $i$. I can prove that $f$ attains a global minimum on the set $\{
g=0,r_1,r_2,r_3>0\}$. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: How do you know that the global minimum is attained at $(r,r,2r)$?

Comment: $r_1 = r_2, r_3 = r_1 + r_2$ is not the minimum. How did you arrive at that conclusion? What Lagrange multiplier method gave you seems to be the minimum. But you could have simplified your working.

Answer (score 1):

Calling

$$
L(r_k,\lambda) = \frac{1}{6}(r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2)-\left(\frac{1}{r_1^3}+\frac{1}{r_2^3}+\frac{1}{r_3^3}\right)-\lambda\left(\frac{1}{3}(r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2)-3\left(\frac{1}{r_1^3}+\frac{1}{r_2^3}+\frac{1}{r_3^3}\right)\right)
$$

the stationary points for this lagrangian are the solutions for

$$
0=\nabla L = \cases{9-27\lambda-(2\lambda-1)r_k^5, \ \ \{k=1,2,3\}\\
\frac{1}{3}(r_1^2+r_2^2+r_3^2)-3\left(\frac{1}{r_1^3}+\frac{1}{r_2^3}+\frac{1}{r_3^3}\right)
}
$$

now substituting the found $r_k^*(\lambda)$ into the restriction we get  $\lambda^* = \frac 25$ and then $r_k = 3^{\frac 25}$ so apparently we have only a stationary point. This point seems to be a global minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I write $x$ instead of $r.$  Your question is equivalent to minimizing
$${1\over 18}(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) \tag1$$
subject to
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=9\big(  \frac{1}{x_1^3}+\frac{1}{x_2^3}+\frac{1}{x_3^3}   \big) \tag2 $$
Applying the Lagrange multiplier method to (1) and (2), we conclude that the minimum occurs when $x_1=x_2=x_3.$
Solving (2) under this condition gives $x_1=x_2=x_3=\sqrt[5]9.$ Thus, the minimum value is $1\over 2\sqrt[5]3$.

Comment: Note that the problem is symmetric with respect to the exchange of any two variables.